# How to use fetchedResultsController to return only certain entities?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Right now the setupFetchedResultsController in my program returns all the Entities of type "Food", but I only want Entities of type "Food" that are also heldBy the "List" entity I am currently displaying.

heldBy defines the relationship between "Food" and "List"

Is there a way to do this?

My setupFetchedResultsController

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    // 1 - Decide what Entity you want
    NSString *entityName = @"Food"; // Put your entity name here
    NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

    // 2 - Request that Entity
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

    // 3 - Filter it if you want
    //request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Role.name = Blah"];

    // 4 - Sort it if you want
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                      ascending:YES
                      selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
    // 5 - Fetch it
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                      managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                      cacheName:nil];
    [self performFetch];
}
```

Comment: The code looks like only getting Food entity. Even Food.heldBy is pointing a List entity, you can ignore it no?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. Food.heldBy does point to a List entity, but why would I ignore that?

I have many Food Items, but only want to display the Food Items that are in a certain List.

Comment: wow it was right in front of me and i didn't see it. thanks! problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use predicate that you comment out.

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"heldBy.name = name_of_list"];
```